# Spring Loaded Pin with Chamfered Pin Finish?

Tags: springs

I would like to try out a component that operates like a combination of the two pictures provided - spring loaded pull pin, with a pin finish like a tubular latch (chamfered/filleted finish).

Do these exist?

If somebody can tell me their correct name or better still, provide me with a link to a manufacturer's site that would be great.

Thank you

[image: Spring Loaded Pull Pin]
[image: Chamfered/Filleted Pin Finish]

Comment: I’m not sure it exists, but you could get the top one, and grind the shape you want on the end of the pin. That said, you may find a detent with a spherical end which may work for you. Browse Carr-lane or McMaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please note that (since there is a huge amount of manufacturers) it is not our job to look for your part. But as starting point:

Here are some sites where you can look for an index plunger. There is a ton of options but on first glance I couldn't make out the smae type you were looking for. It's likely that you have to resort to GisMofx's hack and grind/mill the bevel on the standard part.

- [Norelem](https://www.norelem.com/us/en/Products/Product-overview/Flexible-standard-component-system/03000-Spring-plungers-Indexing-plungers-Stops-Centring-positioning-components-Ball-lock-pins-T-slot-nuts/Indexing-plungers.html)
- [Ganter](https://www.ganternorm.com/en/products/3.1-Indexing-locking-blocking-with-pins-and-ball-shaped-elements/Indexing-plungers)
- [Halder](https://www.halder.com/gb/Products/Standard-Parts/Machine-and-Fixture-Elements/Index-Plungers-Index-Bolts)
- [Carr-Lane](https://www.carrlane.com/en-us/product/spring-loaded-devices/index-plungers)

I'll extend this list to more sources whan people comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GisMofx and M.Bauer for the advice, those website will come in handy for future research.

Norelem actually have one, which can be found [here](https://www.norelem.com/us/en/Products/Product-overview/Flexible-standard-component-system/03000-Spring-plungers-Indexing-plungers-Stops-Centring-positioning-components-Ball-lock-pins-T-slot-nuts/Indexing-plungers/03089-10-Indexing-plungers-with-rotation-lock-and-lead-in-chamfer.html).

I also found a spring-loaded slide bolt latch from McMaster-Carr which will also suit what I need ([Link](https://www.mcmaster.com/2206a21)).